Problem installing keycloak as a service using nssm
I am trying to install keycloak using nssm and have used the following commands:
nssm.exe install "Keycloak" "C:\Keycloak\keycloak-24.0.2\bin\kc.bat"
nssm.exe set "Keycloak" AppDirectory "C:\Keycloak\keycloak-24.0.2\bin\"
nssm.exe set "Keycloak" Description "Keycloak Identity and Access Management"
nssm.exe set keycloak AppParameters start-dev

The service installs but fails when I try to start it. I do notice that the Path to executable goes to nssm.exe instead of kc.bat. The error and logs don't help.
What am I doing wrong?
I tried using nssm to install keycloak batch file kc.bat as a service with parameter start-dev. I was expecting the service to install and run the batch file.

Try This

you can use the following commands:

nssm install Keycloak "D:\Keycloak\keycloak-26.0.5\bin\kc.bat"
nssm set "Keycloak" AppDirectory "D:\Keycloak\keycloak-26.0.5\bin"
nssm set "Keycloak" AppParameters start
nssm set "Keycloak" Description "Keycloak Identity and Access Management"


Or, you can use a GUI:

nssm install Keycloak

